# I receive a wrong receiver email from PayPal IPN PHP

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have an online shop with payments via PayPal. My PayPal IPN script works fine most of the times, but from time to time I get an error that I have no idea how to fix.

My main PayPal email (where I should receive the payments) is something like: besttest.email@gmail.com, but the "receiver_email" field I receive from PayPal sometimes is bestest.email@gmail.com (there is a "t" missing).
A user could have tried to modify the email, but that even happened to me while doing some testing.

Does someone have any idea why this could be happening? I repeat, most of the times it works fine, just lets say one out of 25 the receiver email is wrong.

I noticed another response field from PayPal called "business", which in my case is also my main PayPal email. One way to solve my problem would be to add a condition like:

```
if ($receiver_email == $myPayPalEmail || $business == $myPayPalEmail ) {
   // Do stuff
}
```

I'm not an expert but that doesn't feel safe for the business...

I would really appreciate any advice on that!

Comment: Hard to offer any meaningful advice without examining the full text of the IPN as well as the site you've implemented this on. Contact PayPal directly for support if you don't want to ask a public forum.